# Do outgoing emails using JavaMail through Gmail/Sendgrid SMTP count towards Mail API limits in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm running an app on the Google App Engine standard environment. We need to send out a lot of emails and it looks like App Engine now lets us use JavaMail to send emails using SMTP - connecting to smtp.gmail.com or smtp.sendgrid.net.

I was wondering if this counts towards the Mail API limits/quotas in App Engine. I'm guessing it shouldn't, since the email is actually sent by the respective SMTP server and it's only outbound traffic from App Engine. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Note: I'm not a Java user, the answer is based on documentation only.

Indeed, using 3rd party partner mail services is the Google recommendation for sending lots of emails. From [Quotas and limits](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/mail/#quotas_and_limits):

> Each Mail service request counts toward the **Mail API Calls** quota.
>   There are also quotas for the number of messages you can send, the
>   number of Admin messages you can send, and the amount of data and
>   attachments you can send. For more details, see [Mail quotas](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Mail).
>
> [...]
>
> If you need to send more mail then the quota allows, you can use a
>   third-party mail provider, such as [SendGrid](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/mail/sendgrid) or [Mailgun](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/mail/mailgun).

And JavaMail can, indeed, use these 3rd party SMTP servers. From [Sending email messages](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/mail/sending-mail-with-mail-api#sending_email_messages):

> To send email messages, use the JavaMail classes included with the App
>   Engine SDK.
>
> When you create a JavaMail Session, if you do not provide any SMTP
>   server configuration, App Engine uses the Mail service for sending
>   messages. Alternatively, add SMTP configuration for supported
>   third-party mail providers such as [Mailgun](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/mail/mailgun), [Mailjet](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/mail/mailjet), or
>   [SendGrid](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/mail/sendgrid).

This last quote *appears* (depending on how you interpret it, I guess) to support your assumption that when SMTP servers are specified the Mail service would not be used, thus those calls wouldn't be counted against the Mail API Calls quota.

Also each of the 3rd-party mail integration documentation page referenced in these quotes doesn't (or at least doesn't directly) use JavaMail, instead they require specific libraries/modules. Which *might* have some relationship with bypassing the GAE Mail Api quota limits. For example, from [Sending Email with SendGrid](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/mail/sendgrid):

> Sending an email
>
> It's easy to get started with the [Java library](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-google-java) for SendGrid to
>   send emails from your App Engine apps.
>
> With the [prerequisites](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/mail/sendgrid#before_you_begin) complete, make sure you are [set up for
>   Java](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/gettingstarted/) on your local machine. The last thing you'll need before
>   writing code is to copy [Sendgrid.java](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-google-java) to the `src` directory of
>   your app. You'll import this class so that you can create a SendGrid
>   instance and send mail with simple commands.

So, to gain certainty, my suggestion is to actually put your assumption to the test: send some emails using JavaMail while specifying your SMTP server info, then check your actual usage in the developer console [Quotas](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/quotadetails) page for matching increases. Notes:

- give some ample room for propagation delays - the usage counts *might* not be immediately updated
- if you don't see the `Mail` section in the Usage table check also, towards the bottom of the page, a `Show resources not in use` button/link (but, if it's in there, it means the usage is zero).

You could also directly follow the recommended specific instructions for your 3rd party provider of choice and practically avoid the question altogether :)

Comment: Thank you for responding. I can't test it by checking the quota page since our staging and live apps both send actual App Engine Mail (that counts) throughout the day. I can't use the Sendgrid API since its HTTP-based and I can't upload large attachments due to 1-minute AppEngine timeout limit.

Comment: Yes, you want to send real emails for this test - you want them counted if they are indeed counted - that's the whole idea. But you don't have to fill the quota, you only need to send a few emails and see if they are counted or not. Even one should suffice.